# How to add collection filter to gridContainer in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, collection, grid, filter, grid-layout

I need to add a collection filter to my grid. I do few search on Internet but unfortunately it can't resolve my case.

I'm using **gridContainer** instead of usual way.

Here is my files:

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="test_module_listing"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**ui_component.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_modules_listing.integration_upload_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">test_modules_listing.integration_upload_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">test_modules_columns</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="test_modules_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">TestGridDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">test_modules_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">unique_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/bookmarks/bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/save"/>
                        <item name="deleteUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/delete"/>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">test_modules_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <container name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_modules_listing.test_modules_listing.test_modules_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </container>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/search/search</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridFilters</item>
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_modules_listing.integration_upload_listing_data_source</item>
                    <item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">test_modules_listing.test_modules_listing.listing_top.listing_filters_chips</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_modules_listing.test_modules_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filterSearch>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridFilters</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">filters</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_modules_listing.test_modules_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_modules_listing.test_modules_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">test_modules_listing.test_modules_listing.listing_top.bookmarks:current.columns.${ $.index }.visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <filterRange name="unique_id">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">unique_id</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                        <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_modules_listing.test_modules_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <filterInput name="from">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">from</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">from</item>
                            <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string" translate="true">From</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </filterInput>
                <filterInput name="to">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">to</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">to</item>
                            <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string" translate="true">To</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </filterInput>
            </filterRange>
            ......
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">test_modules_listing.test_modules_listing.test_modules_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">unique_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="customerexport/upload/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_modules_listing.test_modules_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">test_modules_listing.test_modules_listing.test_modules_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">bottom</item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="20" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">20</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="30" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">30</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="50" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">50</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="100" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">100</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="200" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">200</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns name="test_modules_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_modules_listing.test_modules_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_modules_listing.test_modules_listing.test_modules_columns.actions</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="controlVisibility" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_modules_listing.test_modules_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">unique_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>

        <column name="unique_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        ....
        <column name="source_type">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Test\Modules\Model\Something\Source\SourceType</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Source Type</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Test\Modules\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\TestActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">unique_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Test\Modules\Api\Data\TestInterface" type="Test\Modules\Model\Test" />
<virtualType name="TestGridFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
            <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<virtualType name="TestGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Test\Modules\Model\Resource\Test\Collection</argument>
        <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">TestGridFilterPool</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<virtualType name="Test\Modules\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">test_modules_test</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Test\Modules\Model\ResourceModel\Test</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="test_modules_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Test\Modules\Model\ResourceModel\Upload\Test\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
</config>
```

Well, the final **di.xml** is from another module which I will call it module **A**, module **A** collection and grid collection are being used by module **B**, **C**,..etc

**layout.xml** (file in view/adminhtml/layout folder) and **ui_component.xml** (file in view/adminhtml/ui_component folder) are files from children modules (B, C, ... Z).

The concept here is keep module A does everything for its children, it suppose to has only one collection and only one data source.

The questions are:

- Is is possible to filter a collection if keep using GridContainer (`Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Container`) in Magento 2?
- Why `Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Container` doesn't have `_prepareCollection()` method?
- How to override `_prepareCollection()` if my **Block.php** is extending from `Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Container`

I tried to put a Grid.php under `Test\Modules\Block\Adminhtml\Test` but it just simply not working.

**Grid.php**

```
<?php
namespace Test\Modules\Block\Adminhtml\Test;

class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid
{
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $this->setDefaultFilter(array('field_need_to_filter' => 'value'));
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
}
```

## UPDATED (05/05/16: 1462431094)

Here is my collection file

**Collection.php**

```
<?php
namespace Test\Modules\Model\ResourceModel\Test;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_idFieldName = 'unique_id';

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Test\Modules\Model\Test', 'Test\Modules\Model\ResourceModel\Test');
    }
}
```

## UPDATED (05/05/16: 1462438671)

There is no separate collection for grid (You can know that by reading my **di.xml**).

## UPDATED (05/05/16: 1462440386)

In case you don't like to read. I would like to add different filter to different modules. Those modules are extending from module **A**, this can be done by create multiple different collection in my module **A**. But I don't like that, I feel comfortable with my current structure. Keep it be unique and other modules must extend and call it father.

All I need now is how to add a filter in **Grid**(s)

Does it make sense?

Comment: Do you have `Test\Modules\Model\ResourceModel\Upload\Test\Collection` collection file? If yes update your question with code of collection file.

Comment: @PrashantValanda: Please check, I've just added collection file.

Comment: Is this separate collection for grid? Have you created separate collection file for grid?

Comment: @PrashantValanda There is no separate collection for grid. Take a look on my **di.xml**

Comment: You can use $this->addFieldToFilter('field_need_to_filter', ['eq'=>'value']) in the protected _initSelect method of your collection.

Answer (score 0):

Create a collection file for grid code as below:

```
<?php

namespace Test\Modules\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Search\AggregationInterface;
use Test\Modules\Model\ResourceModel\Upload\Test\Collection as TestCollection;


class Collection extends TestCollection implements SearchResultInterface
{

    protected $aggregations;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document',
        $connection,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory,
            $logger,
            $fetchStrategy,
            $eventManager,
            $storeManager,
            $connection,
            $resource
        );
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    }


    public function getAggregations()
    {
        return $this->aggregations;
    }


    public function setAggregations($aggregations)
    {
        $this->aggregations = $aggregations;
    }



    public function getAllIds($limit = null, $offset = null)
    {
        return $this->getConnection()->fetchCol($this->_getAllIdsSelect($limit, $offset), $this->_bindParams);
    }


    public function getSearchCriteria()
    {
        return null;
    }


    public function setSearchCriteria(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }


    public function getTotalCount()
    {
        return $this->getSize();
    }


    public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
    {
        return $this;
    }


    public function setItems(array $items = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Replace below code in di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="test_modules_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Test\Modules\Model\ResourceModel\Upload\Test\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Replce to:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="test_modules_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Test\Modules\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: It doesn't help at all. It works exactly like my current collection. I used Dependency Injection, thanks Magento 2 for this new and powerful feature.
What I need here is how to add a different filter for different children modules. Thanks anyway.

Comment: By the way: There is no `Test\Modules\Model\ResourceModel\Upload\Test\Collection` in my di.xml, it already defined by my virtualType

Answer (score 0):

Add filter in ui component dataSource tag
**uicomponent.xml**

```
<dataSource name="vtn_unexportedorder_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">vtn_unexportedorder_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="status" xsi:type="string">pending</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
```

In above code added filter_url_params and apply filter where status equals to pending, Here I am getting only pending orders

```
<item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="status" xsi:type="string">pending</item>
</item>
```